# Чтение повторяющихся узлов в один выходной узел

Tags: xml, xslt

Есть несколько элементов с одинаковым именем, но разными значениями, например:

```
<itemp>1</item>
<itemp>2</item>
<itemp>3</item>
<itemp>4</item>
```

Необходимо с помощью xslt записать их в выходной файл в один параметр через запятую. В конце запятой не должно быть. Это было бы просто, если бы в xslt значения переменных можно было менять. Может кто-нибудь подскажет, как это сделать в xslt 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так?

```
<xsl:for-each select="//item">
  <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
  <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: спасибо, очень помогли